# How to set image to the UISegmentedControl in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new to iPhone development. I have created UISegmentedControl having 2 segments. I want to display images for each segment instead of title. Here is my code

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"segment1", @"segment2", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(5,100,300,40);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];
```

But instead of displaying the title ,segment1 and segment2 it should be replaced with the images I have.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is almost exactly what you had, just pass an array of UIImages instead of NSStrings.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment2.png"],
    nil];
```

Comment: Is it possible to have text and image both on segmented control?

Comment: @AppleDeveloper, nope.

Comment: Although it is possible to set both a label and an image for a segment, a segment should have one or the other, as described in macOS Human Interface Guidelines.       https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SegmentedControl/Articles/SegmentedControlCode.html

Answer (score 24):

If you want to change the image during runtime, use the following method:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

e.g.:

```
[segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment1.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Is it possible to have text and image both on segmented control?

Comment: Nope. Only one "title" or "image".

Comment: @applefreak 10 years later, yes you can have both in one segmented control

Answer (score 13):

It's simple to do it with **Interface Builder** (*Attributes Inspector* tab).

[image: Image setting with IB]

Also you can set one segment with image and the other one with text.

[image: Result]

Happy xCoding! )

Comment: My segment control will not display any image in the segments

Answer (score 5):

For interface builder user, set "render as" as "original image" rather than default. In my case, it will show after running. It may work. 
@jcpennypincher
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

In xcode 4.6.3 there is an option in interface builder to add an image to the segment controls.