# How to fit an image inside SegmentController programmatically - Swift

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to setup an image inside SegmentController - Swift.

```
    let testTypeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {

    let types = [“Green”, “Blue”] // v_concreteSelectedIndex
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: types)
    sc.setImage((UIImage(named: "Green_Main.png")), forSegmentAt: 0)

    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = .black

    return sc
}()
```

How to fix the image properly inside the segment controller.

I tried:

```
sc.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

but seems it didn't worked well.

I tried to use constrain but I have no idea how to do it.

Any advise how to proceed?

Comment: What was the reason of downvoting?

Comment: Try to give color instead of image if possible

Comment: I can use color, but I am interested to learn how to use photo.

Comment: Check solution in this link may be it can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001313/how-to-set-image-to-the-uisegmentedcontrol-in-iphone OR try to give clipsToBounds = true.

Comment: I have checked this previously, it is not what I am looking for, I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: Did you try clipsToBounds = true ?

Comment: @XinLok can you see your segment control without image?

Comment: @GovindKumawat yes, the only issue is that the photo need to be resized inside the segment controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not what you expected because the original .png image you are using higher in resolution. You should never use a "big" image to display only a small picto. The full image will be loaded in memory, and only 10% of its pixels will be displayed, so you will use a lot of memory for nothing.

What you can do if you really want to use this resource is to create a new image with code before, and use this new generated image.

The following method returns a new image you can use in your `UISegmentedControl`, and you can release the big one.

```
func image(with image: UIImage?, scaledTo newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
```

In your code:

```
    let testTypeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["One", "Two"])
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sc
    }()


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(testTypeSegmentedControl)

    let newImage = image(with: (UIImage(named: "watermelon.png")), scaledTo: CGSize(width: 32, height: 30))
    testTypeSegmentedControl.setImage(newImage , forSegmentAt: 0)

}
```

Comment: Man, this is great explanation which can be used everywhere. thanks a lot